# JS: element.style = value; first time not executed when appearing twice

Tags: javascript, css

For a website I made a JS, to animate a div upon scroll. I was animating the CSS top value, but since I had a transition applied to that property, I had to come up with a way of animating "top" without the lag that CSS transitions results in.

I came up with this inside a function:

```
//Get the Div Element
var div = document.querySelector('.someclass');

//Disable Transition
div.style.transition= 'none';

//Change the top value - value was connected to scroll
div.style.top = anumber + 'px';

//Reset Transition to the CSS's file default
div.style.transition = '';
```

But this resulted in the unwanted lag again, because it somehow ignored the "Disable Transition" step.

To make sure that each step would be executed, I came up with the Idea to wrap the "Reset" step into a setTimeout function. I changed this line:

```
//Reset Transition to the CSS's file default
div.style.transition = '';

to

//Reset Transition to the CSS's file default
setTimeout(function () {
   div.style.transition = '';
},1);
```

And Tadaa, it worked. But now I'm wondering, if there was a cleaner way to prevent the first line of not being executed, and of course an explenation why it even happened.

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to the DOM only get reflected to the underlying model when the CSS engine runs, which only happens if JS stopped running. By using `setTimeout` the execution of JS ends, the CSS engine has time to run, then the timer fires and JS runs again.

You could solve ut a bit more elegantly with:

```
 const tick = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));

 (async function() {
   //Get the Div Element
   var div = document.querySelector('.someclass');
   //Disable Transition
   div.style.transition= 'none';
   //Change the top value - value was connected to scroll
   div.style.top = anumber + 'px';

   await tick();

   //Reset Transition to the CSS's file default
  div.style.transition = '';
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For some reasons, this doesn't work for me when using `requestAnimationFrame(resolve)` but works with `setTimeout(resolve, 0)`, any ideas why?

Comment: @josias Whoops, microtasks. `requestAnimationFrame` triggers before the next rerender, and Promises might also resolve in microtask, so all of that might happen before the rerender, `setTimeout` always creates a task